# Using .getline with string instead of char

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

So I have some code here that reads from a text document and stores it into `char bunz`. I know this sounds like a stupid question but I'd rather use `string` instead of char. Will `.getline` accept a string if it is used with `ifstream`? Or will I be forced to convert the char to a string afterwords?

Thanks.

```
ifstream filler("C:\\bunz.txt");

char bunz[30+1];
filler.getline(bunz, 40);
cout<<bunz;
filler.close();
```

Comment: Don't use `.getline` at all. Just use the free version of `getline`.

Comment: @chris: You have a tendency to post comments that should be answers, why is that? Is it timidity?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley exactly. I feel positively guilty for posting that answer, but I know he won't. Sometimes I think its because he just doesn't find it "interesting" enough.

Comment: I guess answer questions takes time, need to massage wording, sometimes it's repeating work.

Comment: I was kind of doing something else, but I guess it does only take a few more seconds to throw in an example. Is there answer therapy around here? I need to be reprogrammed to click the box down there.

Comment: @chris  srsly. many times your comments are far far better answers than the ones that are eventually accepted. Post one below for this (cut and past mine, i don't care), and I'll *gladly* up-vote it.

Comment: @WhozCraig, No need now. Yours is correct and has a correct example that shows how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notorious for posting answers as comments, chris is *spot on*. Once you use `std::getline()`, you'll *never* go back:

```
ifstream filler("C:\\bunz.txt");
string bunz;
getline(filler, bunz);
cout<<bunz;
filler.close();
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks chris and craig